# Is this possible convert a Codeigniter project into phone gap?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4

Currently I'm using codeigniter4 How can I integrate? please define briefly I'm a fresher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. PhoneGap is HTML and Javascript based. Your PHP code won't run.

Even if you would have a HTML/JS project only you wouldn't be able to use it 1-on-1. You would have to implement PhoneGap hooks etc. to make it run properly.

Comment: Sir, can you share me article to implement it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? an article on how to build an app with phonegap? Again, your codeigniter app won't work

Comment: Sir How can I Implement it with PhoneGap hooks to make it properly?

Comment: That is only possible with a normal HTML/JS app and you would probably be best of starting a new project and copying your code over bit-by-bit